# what's the geder of PaRDeS?

Tags: pardes

It's known (as explained and sourced in [Kuntres Inyana Chassidus 5726](https://the-eye.eu/public/Books/Occult_Library/Qabalah/Rabbi%20Menachem%20M.%20Schneerson%20-%20On%20the%20Essence%20of%20Chassidus.pdf)) that there are 4 levels of Torah Interpretation, regarding any idea of it -- Pshat (simple meaning), Remez (how it hints or alludes to something else), Derush (how it teaches us something else that's not part of the simple meaning), and Sod (how the Torah idea is manifested in the spiritual worlds), [and Chassidus is the 5th level which encompasses all of them etc. see there)

It says in [Hilchos Yesodei haTorah halacha 9 and 12](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/904960/jewish/Yesodei-haTorah-Chapter-One.htm):

> 9
>
> If so, what is the meaning of the expressions employed by the Torah:
>   "Below His feet" [Exodus 24:10], "Written by the finger of God" [ibid.
>   31:18], "God's hand" [ibid. 9:3], "God's eyes" [Genesis 38:7], "God's
>   ears" [Numbers 11:1], and the like?
>
> All these [expressions were used] to relate to human thought processes
>   which know only corporeal imagery, for the Torah speaks in the
>   language of man. They are only descriptive terms, as [apparent from
>   Deuteronomy 32:41]: "I will whet My lightning sword." Does He have a
>   sword? Does He need a sword to kill? Rather, this is metaphoric
>   imagery. [Similarly,] all [such expressions] are metaphoric imagery.
>
> A proof of this concept: One prophet says that he saw the Holy One,
>   blessed be He, "clothed in snow white" [Daniel 7:9], and another
>   envisioned Him [coming] "with crimson garments from Batzra" [Isaiah
>   63:1]. Moses, our teacher, himself envisioned Him at the [Red] Sea as
>   a mighty man, waging war, and, at Mount Sinai, [saw Him] as the leader
>   of a congregation, wrapped [in a tallit].
>
> This shows that He has no image or form. All these are merely
>   expressions of prophetic vision and imagery and the truth of this
>   concept cannot be grasped or comprehended by human thought. This is
>   what the verse [Job 11:7] states: "Can you find the comprehension of
>   God? Can you find the ultimate bounds of the Almighty?" ט
>
> אם כן מהו זה שכתוב בתורה ותחת רגליו כתובים באצבע אלהים יד ה' עיני ה'
>   אזני ה' וכיוצא בדברים האלו הכל לפי דעתן של בני אדם הוא שאינן מכירין
>   אלא הגופות ודברה תורה כלשון בני אדם והכל כנויים הן שנאמר אם שנותי ברק
>   חרבי וכי חרב יש לו ובחרב הוא הורג אלא משל והכל משל ראיה לדבר שנביא אחד
>   אומר שראה הקדוש ברוך הוא לבושיה כתלג חיור ואחד ראהו חמוץ בגדים מבצרה
>   משה רבינו עצמו ראהו על הים כגבור עושה מלחמה ובסיני כשליח צבור עטוף
>   לומר שאין לו דמות וצורה אלא הכל במראה הנבואה ובמחזה ואמתת הדבר אין
>   דעתו של אדם מבין ולא יכולה להשיגו ולחקרו וזה שאמר הכתוב החקר אלוה תמצא
>   אם עד תכלית שדי תמצא:
>
> 12
>
> Since this is so, all such [descriptions] and the like which are
>   related in the Torah and the words of the Prophets - all these are
>   metaphors and imagery. [For example,] "He who sits in the heavens
>   shall laugh" [Psalms 2:4], "They angered Me with their emptiness"
>   [Deuteronomy 32:21], and "As God rejoiced" [ibid. 28:63]. With regard
>   to all such statements, our Sages said: "The Torah speaks in the
>   language of man."
>
> This is [borne out by the rhetorical question (Jeremiah 7:19):] "Are
>   they enraging Me?" Behold, [Malachi 3:6] states: "I, God, have not
>   changed." Now were He to at times be enraged and at times be happy, He
>   would change. Rather, all these matters are found only with regard to
>   the dark and low bodies, those who dwell in houses of clay, whose
>   foundation is dust. In contrast, He, blessed be He, is elevated and
>   exalted above all this. יב
>
> והואיל והדבר כן הוא כל הדברים הללו וכיוצא בהן שנאמרו בתורה ובדברי
>   נביאים הכל משל ומליצה הן כמו שנאמר יושב בשמים ישחק כעסוני בהבליהם כאשר
>   שש ה' וכיוצא בהן על הכל אמרו חכמים דברה תורה כלשון בני אדם וכן הוא
>   אומר האותי הם מכעיסים הרי הוא אומר אני ה' לא שניתי ואילו היה פעמים
>   כועס ופעמים שמח היה משתנה וכל הדברים האלו אינן מצויין אלא לגופים
>   האפלים השפלים שוכני בתי חומר אשר בעפר יסודם אבל הוא ברוך הוא יתברך
>   ויתרומם על כל זה:
>   that "the Torah speaks in the language of man", in a way of metaphors, when describing the nature of G-d, so if so: what category does that fall under in ParDas? Is that the plain simple meaning (that its only an allegory) or is the simple meaning actually that Hashem has a body (chas veshalom)?

**In other words, in what category of PaRDeS do the metaphors describing G-d, fall under?**

Comment: Would you consider that Rambam didn't buy into that 4-fold division of interpretation?

Comment: @DoubleAA No I would not consider that at all

Comment: As far as I know, the 4 fold division of Torah known as PaRDeS appeared after Rambam's time. It may have been known to a select few, but it doesn't appear in any texts until about 100 years before Rabbi Moshe Kordevero. (Ramak) And even then, the meaning used today (Peshat, Remez, Drush & Sod, which follows the teaching of the Ari z"l) was not universal. I have seen (Peshat, Remez, Dat & Sod).

Comment: @YaacovDeane did you read the source linked?

Comment: @Yaakov5777 If you’re referring to the pamphlet by the Rebbe, yes. If you’re referring to the Mishnah Torah link, I don’t know what you are referencing in it in regard to the division of PaRDeS.

Answer (score -1):

The general rule I learned from R' Shlezinger is:
If it does not include reasoning, e.g. if one understands it "as is" it's Peshat.

If the text says "God's hands" and you understand it as God's hands, it is Peshat. The further clarifications like G-d does not have hands etc have nothing to do with understanding the verse. But if the verse says "ושננתם לבניך" and you conclude that because the students are treated like sons this verse speaks about students, it's not Peshat.

Comment: I agree with your second part about ושננתם לבניך but not your part about God's hands.  By that logic you'd also have to conclude in the peshat that a [river](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.2.5) has a hand for example.  There's some level of common sense that's required even for peshat.

Comment: Respectfully, that makes no sense. This division means that one person’s pshat could be another person’s derash or even sod.

Comment: @Heshy What river and what hand?

Comment: @DonielF I don't understand. we all use the word hand as hand. Not as branch or sescendents or else. So if it says G-d's hand the Pshat means hand with fingers etc (see the questions about G-d's finger wriing the Luchos). But if we use two step or more analogies it is not Pshat.

Comment: @AlBerko You say that "If it does not include reasoning, e.g. if one understands it 'as is' it's Peshat." If I require several steps of exposition to understand the passuk that way, while you're so familiar with the Gemaras that when you see the term X you know automatically that it means Y, then it's much more peshat for you than it is for me. (Btw I was not the one who downvoted.)

Comment: @DonielF I agree that some are so used to certain terms they might think it is Pshat, for example Avraham being Chesed and Itzhak Gvuros etc. But it isn't. דברה התורה בלשון בני אדם - the simple understanding of words, as a 5-year-old would understand. We add levels of sophistication but that's not Pshat. Regarding G-d, the Torah says בצלמנו כדמותנו explicitly assuming that G-d has all human organs.

Comment: Did you click on the link?  It says על יד היאור, therefore a river has a hand unless you think about it for a second.

Comment: @AlBerko Be *very* careful with that line of logic. Taking that to the extreme, you can conclude some things that are complete heresy by saying that the simple reading is always a correct and valid approach. Consider עין תחת עין - not only is the simple reading wrong, it's also contradictory to several other pesukim.

Comment: @Heshy do you speak Hebrew at all? When I ask you "do you speak" does it mean that you "DO" AND "speak"? No Hebrew speaker understands על יד as "by the hand of". I expected more from you.

Comment: @DonielF We only discussed what the Pshat is. עין תחת עין means by the Pshat that eye in exchange for an eye. If we don't Pasken so has nothing to do with the Pshat. What do you say about  וַיֵּלֶךְ רְאוּבֵן וַיִּשְׁכַּב אֶת בִּלְהָה פִּילֶגֶשׁ אָבִיו ? That's the Pshat.  I never said Pshat is accepted for Halacha or overrides Drash etc. For that we have a rule of אין הדבר יוצא מידי פשוטו https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%90_%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%93%D7%99_%D7%A4%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%98%D7%95#מקור_הכלל

Comment: Then I guess no Hebrew speaker understands https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.41.42  You have to use common sense and figure out what it means from context.  For a human it means a hand.   For God or a river it doesn't.

Comment: @AlBerko Please read the second part of my comment. אין מקרא יוצא מידי פשוטו doesn’t help if you have Pesukim that contradict each other.

Comment: @DonielF You mean "*Consider עין תחת עין - not only is the simple reading wrong, it's also contradictory to several other pesukim.*" 1. Please elaborate what's "wrong" with literal meaning? You might say it's not accepted Halachicly but that's what it says. 2. The contradictions in the Pshat are apparent I agree, that's why some try to escalate explanation to a higher level. For example, I love my kids and I take them to a dentist to hurt them - that's the Pshat contradiction. But then they realize the dentist ...

Comment: ... heals them and that's what I meant and that aligns with my love.

Comment: @AlBerko But you agree that their initial, pshat understanding - that you take them there to hurt them - can not be correct. You need to extrapolate based on other information to derive the truth, which you’re understanding to be derash.

Comment: @DonielF As I said, a [possibility of an] interpretation has nothing to do with truth or Halachah, it is just so. If the text says "וַיִּשְׁכַּב אֶת בִּלְהָה" the Pshat is just that. You might then claim - that Pshat is wrong or mistaken, but you can't deny the simple reading. Sometimes we don't know the words and Rashi explains what's the simplest reading of a verse. In my approach, anything that requires "therefore" is not a Pshat.

Comment: @DonielF As I said, if you read this "לֻחֹת הָעֵדֻת לֻחֹת אֶבֶן כְּתֻבִים בְּאֶצְבַּע אֱלֹהִים" to a kid adn ask him "how did G-d wrote the Luchos?" he will show you a finger. You can then ask: "but G-d does not have physical fingers, therefore...?", and he would say: "well something like a finger". That's the difference between the Pshat and everythig else in my approach.

Comment: @DonielF In general, I wonder, even if you find somebody else saying otherwise, why you deny my right to have an opinion? As I constantly claim - there are no clearly defined terms in Judaism, so everyone is free to offer his own definition. Don't you agree?

Comment: @AlBerko G-d forbid, I’m not denying your right to have an opinion. I disagree vehemently with many of your claims, but that doesn’t mean I don’t agree you have a right to an opinion. (Though I *do* disagree with your claim that there are no clearly defined terms in Judaism; that’s another line that you have to tread very carefully in applying, or else you can end up with a completely different Torah just by defining everything differently.)